# Theoremstyle not applied

Tags: color, theorems

I'm writing some exercises, and wanted to add some style to my theorems for fun, it was working well until I opened it today: it doesn't work anymore I don't know why I spend an hour to search why the hell he don't want to set the style, I tried on windows and on Linux, with a minimal page, and still not applying my style...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\newtheorem{thmTest}{THM}
\newtheoremstyle{myStyle}{}{}{\color{myColor}}{}{\color{myColor}\bfseries}{}{}{}
\theoremstyle{myStyle}

\title{Test}
\author{.}
\date{15 10 15}


\begin{document}

\begin{thmTest}
Test
\end{thmTest}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely no way that the code you posted was changing the style for the structure. The declaration of the theorem must be done **after** selecting the style; otherwise, the `plain` style is applied. Additionally, and more important, in the definition of your style the seventh mandatory argument cannot be left empty (otherwise an error is triggered), so at least you'll need something like

```
\newtheoremstyle{myStyle}
  {}
  {}
  {\color{myColor}}
  {}
  {\color{myColor}\bfseries}
  {}
  {.5em}
  {}
\theoremstyle{myStyle}
\newtheorem{thmTest}{THM}
```

A complete example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\newtheoremstyle{myStyle}
  {}
  {}
  {\color{myColor}}
  {}
  {\color{myColor}\bfseries}
  {}
  {.5em}
  {}
\theoremstyle{myStyle}
\newtheorem{thmTest}{THM}

\begin{document}

\begin{thmTest}
test
\end{thmTest}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Perhaps you might change the color since with the current settings the theorem is hard to see.

## Some remarks

- `amssymb` internally loads `amsfonts`, so there's no need to load the latter when the former has been loaded.
- Better to load `xcolor` than `color`.

Comment: god thanks, that's a so stupid error x) thanks a lot ^^